# Time-based testing in Elixir

Tags: testing, elixir

Let's say I have an Elixir function that should do something once every 30 minutes... Or not more often than once every 30 seconds, no matter how often it is called. Is there any good way of testing this, without having the test case take hours?

Comment: Does the function do other things, or is the whole purpose of the function to rate limit?

Answer (score 4):

It is difficult to give an answer without having a specific use case, however one fairly simple option is to have the timeout be configurable (perhaps as a function argument) and test that.

e.g.

```
defmodule MyTest do
  use Exunit.Case

  test "message sent every 100 milliseconds" do
    pid = self
    MyModule.report_count_every(100, pid)
    assert_receive({:ok, 1}, 500)
    assert_receive({:ok, 2}, 500)
  end
end
```

This assumes that `MyModule` is a `GenServer` that maintains a counter which it broadcasts based on the first argument passed to `report_count_every/2`